understanding DMS cloudwatch logs
I am trying to create a DMS replication task using Terraform. The credentials for the endpoint are correct. When I start the replication task, it Fails but the cloudwatch logs aren't that helpful. This is what I see:
....
2024-05-24T07:42:20.000Z    2024-05-24T07:42:20 [SOURCE_CAPTURE ]D: 51) name: 'varchar', SQLType: 12, create params: 'length', unsigned: '-1', iFixedPrecScale: '0', iColumnSize: '255', iMinimumScale '0', iMaximumScale: '0' (ar_odbc_conn.c:1371)
2024-05-24T07:42:20.000Z    2024-05-24T07:42:20 [SOURCE_CAPTURE ]D: Exit ODBC Provider supported data types (ar_odbc_conn.c:1391)
2024-05-24T07:42:20.000Z    2024-05-24T07:42:20 [SOURCE_CAPTURE ]I: Source endpoint 'Mysql' is using provider syntax 'MySQL' (provider_syntax_manager.c:894)
2024-05-24T07:42:20.000Z    2024-05-24T07:42:20 [SOURCE_CAPTURE ]I: Mysql endpoint initialization finished for the stream component (mysql_endpoint_imp.c:808)
2024-05-24T07:42:20.000Z    2024-05-24T07:42:20 [SOURCE_CAPTURE ]D: Entering 'mysql_endpoint_free_imp' (mysql_endpoint_imp.c:879)
2024-05-24T07:42:20.000Z    2024-05-24T07:42:20 [SORTER ]I: Sorter inspect target state (sorter.c:519)
2024-05-24T07:42:20.000Z    2024-05-24T07:42:20 [SORTER ]I: Target state checkpoint source id: 0 (sorter.c:524)
2024-05-24T07:42:20.000Z    2024-05-24T07:42:20 [SORTER ]I: 'Stop reading when memory limit reached' is set to true (sorter.c:688)
2024-05-24T07:42:20.000Z    2024-05-24T07:42:20 [SOURCE_CAPTURE ]D: Leaving 'mysql_endpoint_free_imp' (mysql_endpoint_imp.c:896)
2024-05-24T07:42:20.000Z    2024-05-24T07:42:20 [TARGET_APPLY ]D: Entering 'odbc_endpoint_free_imp' (odbc_endpoint_imp.c:4045)
2024-05-24T07:42:20.000Z    2024-05-24T07:42:20 [TASK_MANAGER ]I: Subtask #0 ended (replicationtask_util.c:595)
2024-05-24T07:42:20.000Z    2024-05-24T07:42:20 [TASK_MANAGER ]I: Task - 222222222222222EEEE is in ERROR state, updating starting status to AR_NOT_APPLICABLE (repository.c:5483)
2024-05-24T07:42:20.000Z    2024-05-24T07:42:20 [TASK_MANAGER ]E: Task '222222222222222EEEEE' encountered a fatal error (repository.c:5580)
2024-05-24T07:42:29.000Z    2024-05-24T07:42:29 [TASK_MANAGER ]I: Task management thread terminated (replicationtask.c:4538)
2024-05-24T07:42:31.000Z    2024-05-24T07:42:31 [AT_GLOBAL ]I: Closing log file at Fri May 24 07:42:31 2024 (at_logger.c:2975)

but I am unable to comprehend it - what exactly is the issue?
Replication Task Mappings:
{
    "rules": [
        {
            "rule-type": "selection",
            "rule-id": "1",
            "rule-name": "1",
            "object-locator": {
                "schema-name": "ti-lv",
                "table-name": "application"

            },
            "rule-action": "include"
        }
    ]
}

Replication Task Settings:
{
  "TargetMetadata": {
    "TargetSchema": "",
    "SupportLobs": true,
    "FullLobMode": false,
    "LobChunkSize": 0,
    "LimitedSizeLobMode": true,
    "LobMaxSize": 512,
    "InlineLobMaxSize": 0,
    "LoadMaxFileSize": 0,
    "ParallelLoadThreads": 0,
    "ParallelLoadBufferSize": 0,
    "BatchApplyEnabled": false,
    "TaskRecoveryTableEnabled": false,
    "ParallelLoadQueuesPerThread": 0,
    "ParallelApplyThreads": 0,
    "ParallelApplyBufferSize": 0,
    "ParallelApplyQueuesPerThread": 0
  },
  "FullLoadSettings": {
    "TargetTablePrepMode": "DROP_AND_CREATE",
    "CreatePkAfterFullLoad": false,
    "StopTaskCachedChangesApplied": false,
    "StopTaskCachedChangesNotApplied": false,
    "MaxFullLoadSubTasks": 2,
    "TransactionConsistencyTimeout": 1200,
    "CommitRate": 20000
  },
  "Logging": {
    "EnableLogging": true,
    "EnableLogContext": false,
    "LogComponents": [
      {
        "Id": "TRANSFORMATION",
        "Severity": "LOGGER_SEVERITY_DEFAULT"
      },
      {
        "Id": "SOURCE_UNLOAD",
        "Severity": "LOGGER_SEVERITY_DEBUG"
      },
      {
        "Id": "IO",
        "Severity": "LOGGER_SEVERITY_DEFAULT"
      },
      {
        "Id": "TARGET_LOAD",
        "Severity": "LOGGER_SEVERITY_DEFAULT"
      },
      {
        "Id": "PERFORMANCE",
        "Severity": "LOGGER_SEVERITY_DEFAULT"
      },
      {
        "Id": "SOURCE_CAPTURE",
        "Severity": "LOGGER_SEVERITY_DEBUG"
      },
      {
        "Id": "SORTER",
        "Severity": "LOGGER_SEVERITY_DEFAULT"
      },
      {
        "Id": "REST_SERVER",
        "Severity": "LOGGER_SEVERITY_DEFAULT"
      },
      {
        "Id": "VALIDATOR_EXT",
        "Severity": "LOGGER_SEVERITY_DEFAULT"
      },
      {
        "Id": "TARGET_APPLY",
        "Severity": "LOGGER_SEVERITY_DEBUG"
      },
      {
        "Id": "TASK_MANAGER",
        "Severity": "LOGGER_SEVERITY_DEFAULT"
      },
      {
        "Id": "TABLES_MANAGER",
        "Severity": "LOGGER_SEVERITY_DEFAULT"
      },
      {
        "Id": "METADATA_MANAGER",
        "Severity": "LOGGER_SEVERITY_DEFAULT"
      },
      {
        "Id": "FILE_FACTORY",
        "Severity": "LOGGER_SEVERITY_DEFAULT"
      },
      {
        "Id": "COMMON",
        "Severity": "LOGGER_SEVERITY_DEFAULT"
      },
      {
        "Id": "ADDONS",
        "Severity": "LOGGER_SEVERITY_DEFAULT"
      },
      {
        "Id": "DATA_STRUCTURE",
        "Severity": "LOGGER_SEVERITY_DEFAULT"
      },
      {
        "Id": "COMMUNICATION",
        "Severity": "LOGGER_SEVERITY_DEFAULT"
      },
      {
        "Id": "FILE_TRANSFER",
        "Severity": "LOGGER_SEVERITY_DEFAULT"
      }
    ]
  },
  "ControlTablesSettings": {
    "FullLoadExceptionTableEnabled": false,
    "ControlSchema": "dms",
    "HistoryTimeslotInMinutes": 5,
    "HistoryTableEnabled": true,
    "SuspendedTablesTableEnabled": true,
    "StatusTableEnabled": true
  },
  "StreamBufferSettings": {
    "StreamBufferCount": 3,
    "StreamBufferSizeInMB": 8,
    "CtrlStreamBufferSizeInMB": 5
  },
  "ChangeProcessingDdlHandlingPolicy": {
    "HandleSourceTableDropped": true,
    "HandleSourceTableTruncated": true,
    "HandleSourceTableAltered": true
  },
  "ErrorBehavior": {
    "EventErrorPolicy": "IGNORE",
    "DataErrorPolicy": "LOG_ERROR",
    "DataTruncationErrorPolicy": "LOG_ERROR",
    "DataErrorEscalationPolicy": "SUSPEND_TABLE",
    "DataErrorEscalationCount": 0,
    "TableErrorPolicy": "SUSPEND_TABLE",
    "TableErrorEscalationPolicy": "STOP_TASK",
    "TableErrorEscalationCount": 0,
    "RecoverableErrorCount": -1,
    "RecoverableErrorInterval": 5,
    "RecoverableErrorThrottling": true,
    "RecoverableErrorThrottlingMax": 1800,
    "RecoverableErrorStopRetryAfterThrottlingMax": true,
    "ApplyErrorDeletePolicy": "IGNORE_RECORD",
    "ApplyErrorInsertPolicy": "LOG_ERROR",
    "ApplyErrorUpdatePolicy": "LOG_ERROR",
    "ApplyErrorEscalationPolicy": "LOG_ERROR",
    "ApplyErrorEscalationCount": 0,
    "ApplyErrorFailOnTruncationDdl": false,
    "FullLoadIgnoreConflicts": true,
    "FailOnTransactionConsistencyBreached": false,
    "FailOnNoTablesCaptured": false
  },
  "FailTaskWhenCleanTaskResourceFailed": false,
  "TTSettings": {
    "EnableTT": false,
    "TTRecordSettings": null,
    "TTS3Settings": null
  },
  "ChangeProcessingTuning": {
    "BatchApplyPreserveTransaction": true,
    "BatchApplyTimeoutMin": 1,
    "BatchApplyTimeoutMax": 30,
    "BatchApplyMemoryLimit": 500,
    "BatchSplitSize": 0,
    "MinTransactionSize": 1000,
    "CommitTimeout": 1,
    "MemoryLimitTotal": 1024,
    "MemoryKeepTime": 60,
    "StatementCacheSize": 50
  },
  "PostProcessingRules": null,
  "CharacterSetSettings": null,
  "LoopbackPreventionSettings": null,
  "BeforeImageSettings": null
}


Does this help: https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/dms-cdc-error-1236-msql?

could you explain what part of my cloudwatch logs hint that this could be the issue(i.e retention period might be low)? cluster's paused over the weekend so can only test next week @MarkoE. and how long should the retention period be?

Nope, I have no idea, I just googled the error. :)

Have you posted this on re/post or created and aws case? The error messages can sometimes be a needle on a haystack. The fact that the error originated from repository.c, to me, means that a data connection was attempted to be made to the target and for whatever reason that failed. I may be helpful to turn on verbose logging to catch sql exceptions at the target such as PK violations or whatnot. Does mysql support traces?

The problem was that the binary logs weren't activated on the MySQL database. I had to search "[E:" in the cloudwatch logs to filter out the relevant ones.
